# HTMLNode to XMLNode?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to convert a (HTMLAgilityPack) HTMLNode to XMLNode?

I have a function;

```
public string GetXPathToNode(XmlNode node)
{
    if (node.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Attribute)
    {
        // attributes have an OwnerElement, not a ParentNode; also they have             
        // to be matched by name, not found by position             
        return String.Format("{0}/@{1}", GetXPathToNode(((XmlAttribute)node).OwnerElement), node.Name);
    }
    if (node.ParentNode == null)
    {
        // the only node with no parent is the root node, which has no path
        return "";
    }

    // Get the Index
    int indexInParent = 1;
    XmlNode siblingNode = node.PreviousSibling;
    // Loop thru all Siblings
    while (siblingNode != null)
    {
        // Increase the Index if the Sibling has the same Name
        if (siblingNode.Name == node.Name)
        {
            indexInParent++;
        }
        siblingNode = siblingNode.PreviousSibling;
    }

    // the path to a node is the path to its parent, plus "/node()[n]", where n is its position among its siblings.         
    return String.Format("{0}/{1}[{2}]", GetXPathToNode(node.ParentNode), node.Name, indexInParent);
}
```

that I need to use to get the XPATH; however, it only allows XMLNode's, not (HTMLAgilityPack) HTMLNode's.

I want to be able to use (HTMLAgilityPack) HTMLNode's or to be able to convert a (HTMLAgilityPack) HTMLNode to XMLNode.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about the HtmlAgilityPack HtmlNode class? Is there some reason why you're unable to rewrite this method to work with HtmlNode?

Comment: Yes I am talking about the HTMLAgilityPack HTMLNode. I don't know how to re write the function to HTMLNode.

Comment: Does HtmlNode have a `NodeType` property? Does it have a `ParentNode` property? What about `Name` and `PreviousSibling`?

Comment: We solve programming problems by breaking them down into smaller pieces and dealing with the pieces one at a time.

Comment: I am not sure if HTMLNode has any of those properties.

Comment: Can you think of any way to find out? Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: I found out that HTMLNode does indeed have those properties.

Comment: However; HtmlNodeType does not have the function . Attribute.

Comment: Right, I thought you might have trouble with that. Does the `HtmlNodeType` type at least exist? What values does it have, if so?

Comment: It has comment, document, element, & text.

Comment: For now, let's try commenting out that whole first `if` statement there. My guess is that you won't be passing HTML attributes to the method anyhow. If that turns out the be the case eventually, you'll have to deal with it then.